# How to use jQuery to correctly print out variables in HTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using the following function to print out the contents of javascript variables.

```
  function message (){
         $("#description").html("Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest][0]+ "%");   

  }
```

This correctly works as expected, however if i try this:

```
  function message (){
    $("#description").html("Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest][0]+ "%");
    $("#description").html("Candidate " + (lowest2+1) + " was the second to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest2][0]+ "%");

  }
```

This obviously doesn't work. The second message overwrites the text of the first message. What is the proper way displaying both messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function message (){
    var output;
    output = "Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest][0]+ "%";
    output += "Candidate " + (lowest2+1) + " was the second to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest2][0]+ "%";
    $("#description").html(output);

  }
```

keep DOM manipulation as few as possible for the sake of the performance (it will save you from unnecessary page repaints): just use a variable to contain all your strings and do the insertion once so to avoid multiple expensive calls to `jQuery` function.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/):

```
function message (){
    $("#description").append("Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest][0]+ "%");
    $("#description").append("Candidate " + (lowest2+1) + " was the second to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest2][0]+ "%");

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
   $("#description").html("Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " +    results[lowest][0]+ "%");
  $("#description").append("Candidate " + (lowest2+1) + " was the second to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest2][0]+ "%");
```

Answer (score 0):

`html()` method will replace all that is in selector....  I think you want `append()` which adds to end of existing html

Answer (score 0):

You need to append, not replace the html of the display element.

So something like this:

```
 $("#description").append("Candidate " + (lowest+1) + " was the first to get eliminated ending on " + results[lowest][0]+ "%" + "<br />");
```

[`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) can take a jQuery object, native DOM element, or plain HTML string.

Depending on how structured your actual data are, a more robust approach would be to build a DOM fragment, then append that to the container:

```
function message (){
  $('<div class="result">').html( _your_message_here_ ).appendTo('#description');
  $('<div class="result">').html( _next_message_here_ ).appendTo('#description');
}
```

Then you can style `div.result` as desired, not worry about line breaks, etc.